# Mouse position in mouseMoveEvent and mousePressEvent are different: QGraphicsObject

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem

Mouse position in mouseMoveEvent and mousePressEvent are different in the following example. This is happening due to the added scaling. Without scaling the positions are same.

Do I have to update the boundingRect according to the changed scaling? How?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from PyQt5.QtCore import (QRectF)
from PyQt5.QtGui import (QPainter, QPixmap)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QApplication, QGraphicsObject, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene)


class TicTacToe(QGraphicsObject):
    def __init__(self, helper):
        super(TicTacToe, self).__init__()
        self.mypixmap = QPixmap("exit1.png")

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        painter.setOpacity(1)

        painter.drawPixmap(0,0, 512, 512, self.mypixmap)
        painter.drawLine(2,2,20,20)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QRectF(0,0,512, 512)


    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        print "aaaaaaaaaa"

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        print "ccccccccccc ", event.pos()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print "bbbbbbbbbbbb", event.pos()


class MyGraphicsView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyGraphicsView, self).__init__()
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene(self)

        self.tic_tac_toe = TicTacToe(self)

        self.myScale = 2
        self.tic_tac_toe.setScale(self.myScale)

        self.setScene(self.scene)
        self.scene.addItem(self.tic_tac_toe)
        self.setMouseTracking(True) 

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        self.tic_tac_toe.keyPressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        print "mouse"        
        self.tic_tac_toe.mouseMoveEvent(event)


class Example(QMainWindow):    
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.y = MyGraphicsView()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.y)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Example()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is caused because you are sending the `QGraphicsView` events to a `QGraphicsObject`. In the case of `QGraphicsView` the event is of the `QMouseEvent` type but in the case of `QGraphicsObject` it is of the `QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent` type. In conclusion, you should not pass the `QGraphicsView` events to the `QGraphicsObject` since they refer to different events with different information.

The `mousePressEvent` event is enabled by default but in the case of the `mouseMoveEvent` event it can not be handled by `QGraphicsObject`, instead you must use `hoverMoveEvent` but these will only work inside the `boundingRect` of the `QGraphicsObject`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from PyQt5.QtCore import (QRectF)
from PyQt5.QtGui import (QPainter, QPixmap)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QApplication, QGraphicsObject, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene)


class TicTacToe(QGraphicsObject):
    def __init__(self, helper):
        super(TicTacToe, self).__init__()
        self.mypixmap = QPixmap("exit1.png")
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        painter.setOpacity(1)
        painter.drawPixmap(0,0, 512, 512, self.mypixmap)
        painter.drawLine(2,2,20,20)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QRectF(0,0,512, 512)

    def hoverMoveEvent(self, event):
        print("ccccccccccc ", event.pos())

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print("bbbbbbbbbbbb", event.pos())


class MyGraphicsView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyGraphicsView, self).__init__()
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene(self)

        self.tic_tac_toe = TicTacToe(self)

        self.myScale = 2
        self.tic_tac_toe.setScale(self.myScale)

        self.setScene(self.scene)
        self.scene.addItem(self.tic_tac_toe)

class Example(QMainWindow):    
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.y = MyGraphicsView()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.y)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Example()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

On the other hand, these points do not coincide with the position in the scene since those coordinates are relative to the item.

For you to understand better we could use the following analogy, let's say you are recording a scene with a camera, the camera's screen is like the `QGraphicsView`, the scene is the `QGraphicsScene` and the actors are the `QGraphicsItem`s and `QGraphicsObject`s. Each of these elements has a different coordinate system.

In the case of `QGraphicsView` your `QMouseEvent` returns coordinates in units of pixels, if you want to convert it to coordinates of the scene you must use `mapToScene()`.

In the case of the `QGraphicsItem`/`QGraphicsObject` have different coordinates to those of the scene, those are not affected by the transformations such as scale, rotation, etc. That is what is printing in the previous example. If you want to convert it to units of the scene you must use `mapToScene()`.

In the following example I show all the impressions in units of the scene.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from PyQt5.QtCore import (QRectF)
from PyQt5.QtGui import (QPainter, QPixmap)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QApplication, QGraphicsObject, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene)


class TicTacToe(QGraphicsObject):
    def __init__(self, helper):
        super(TicTacToe, self).__init__()
        self.mypixmap = QPixmap("exit1.png")
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        painter.setOpacity(1)
        painter.drawPixmap(0,0, 512, 512, self.mypixmap)
        painter.drawLine(2,2,20,20)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QRectF(0,0,512, 512)

    def hoverMoveEvent(self, event):
        #print("hoverMoveEvent ", event.pos())
        print("hoverMoveEvent", self.mapToScene(event.pos()))

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        #print("mousePressEvent", event.pos())
        print("mousePressEvent", self.mapToScene(event.pos()))


class MyGraphicsView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyGraphicsView, self).__init__()
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)

        self.tic_tac_toe = TicTacToe(self)

        self.myScale = 2
        self.tic_tac_toe.setScale(self.myScale)

        self.setScene(self.scene)
        self.scene.addItem(self.tic_tac_toe)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        print("mouseMoveEvent", self.mapToScene(event.pos()))

class Example(QMainWindow):    
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.y = MyGraphicsView()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.y)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Example()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

If you want more information check the following links:

- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html
- http://blog.qt.io/blog/2017/01/19/should-you-be-using-qgraphicsview/

Comment: Am utterly grateful to you. I request you to show the documentation where all this is mentioned so that I can learn too. Thanks.

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl I will add more information in a few moments.